# finding out nearest point to a given point

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two matrix. G1

```
G1 =
   80.00
   79.43
   78.89
   78.38
   77.90
   77.45
   77.03
   76.63
```

and

```
G2 =     NaN       NaN       NaN
         NaN       NaN       NaN
         NaN       79.11     NaN
         NaN       78.64     NaN
         NaN       78.13     78.14
         77.46     NaN       77.66
         77.07     77.08     NaN
         76.74     NaN       NaN
```

I want to have result matrix which has a size of 8*1. Moreover, the G2 matrix elements shoud be compared with G1 and the nearest elements of G2 to G1 shoud be filled up in desired matrix. for example first one of G2 row has NaN, so it keep it NaN. 4th row of G2 has two values, this values should be compared with 4th element of G1 and nearest value shoud be filled up in the result matrix. When there is a single value than it shoud be remain like this only. When there are more than two values than the nearest value shoud be filled up in the matrix.

Below is the desired output. How to do it more dynamically. i just did it by manually.

```
  Result =   NaN
             NaN
             79.11
             78.64
             78.14
             77.46
             77.07
             76.744
```

Comment: Your examples don't make sense. `G1` has 8 rows, `G2` has 7 rows, and your `Result` has 8 rows.

Comment: sorry i missed one row. I just updated it. Thanks you for your reply :)

Comment: Where does the `79.1168` come from? I don't see it in your source data.

Comment: it is only 79.11. I have updated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
dist = abs(bsxfun(@minus,G2,G1))
[~,col] = min(dist,[],2);
Result = diag(G2(:,col))
```

Comment: i mean output shoud be 8*1. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @MayankLakhani see my edit from earlier - you need to add `diag` (or use `sub2ind` if your matrix is really big)